# Enter key form submission fails with HTML5 date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a small HTML form (code below) that is effectively in two parts, and I want users to be able to submit the form by pressing the enter key in only one of these parts ("input" in the code below; the display attributes are toggled by a bit of javascript connected to the selection in the second part of the form).  At the moment, I am handling this with a bit of jQuery/javascript (also below) to bind the enter key press to form submission.

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <span id="input">
        <span id="text" style="display:inline">
            <input type="text">
        </span>
        <span id="dates" style="display:none">
            <input type="date" id="start">
            <input type="date" id="end">
        </span>
    </span>
    <select onchange="changeInput(this.options[selectedIndex].value)">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the jQuery/javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#input").on("click", function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

When the text input is displayed, this works just fine.  When the date inputs are displayed, however, the enter key does nothing.  This is the case whether the browser displays the native calendar widget, or if the inputs are replaced by jQueryUI datepicker widgets in browsers that don't support the date input type (handled by another bit of jQuery/javascript).

Any idea why this is happening?  I'm aware that I could get around it by adding a hidden submit button and overriding the enter key behaviour for the second part of the form, but I would like to understand what's going on first.

Comment: Can you show html getting rendered in browser (with fallback if native html 5 date is not supported)?

Comment: @Regent - Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @SSA - I can't add an image to the post, but I've put one here - [link](http://imgur.com/TLgSEJ5) (Let me know if that doesn't work, I'm new to imgur...)  It shows, in order, text field displayed, date fields displayed, native calendar widget (Chrome), and jQueryUI datepicker (Firefox).  Sorry for the lack of CSS.

Comment: What I mean is, html source in browser for above form/related section.

Comment: @fminl why have you written `e.which == 13`? For `click` event `e.which` can be 1, 2 or 3 (from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)).

Comment: @SSA - Sorry about that.  If I understand you correctly this time, the source in the browser is the same as above, except the span display attributes swap based on the option selected, and `class="hasDatepicker"` is added to the date inputs by jQuery in the fallback.

Comment: @Regent - Arrrgh, that was it!  I inherited that bit of code from someone else and didn't think to check that.  Thanks!

Comment: There is also an input event for input type date, so if you want to submit the form on enter key pressed for selecting the date..you can do this:  $('input[type="date"]').on('input',function(e){
      $("#form").submit();
});

Comment: @Regent - If you want to add that as an answer feel free and I'll accept it, otherwise I'll probably delete this post to avoid filling up the site with my own stupidity.

Comment: @fminl it's a good idea to form it as answer, yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `click` event `e.which` can be 1, 2 or 3 (from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)).

So, for example,  for mouse left click it should be:

```
if (e.which == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I clearly need to check my code better, even when it comes from people with more experience than me.  I'm surprised it worked with the text field though...